# how to assign string for who is going to win the game

Tags: java, if-statement, random

I want to know how to make the code to do such that lets say if newSumDealer > newSumPlayer, then Dealer wins.so far im only getting player wins or its a tie. Im new to java so please help me out here.. give me a clue or so and i will try to figure it out.

edited:

```
//output
 System.out.println( "Player has " +number1+ " , " +number2+ " for a hand worth of ");
  if ( sumPlayer <= 10)
     System.out.println(  +sumPlayer+ " .");
  else if (sumPlayer > 10) {
      sumPlayer = sumPlayer - 10;
   System.out.println( sumPlayer - 10);
    }


  System.out.println( "Dealer has " +number3+ " , " +number4+ " for a hand worth of ");
    if ( sumDealer <= 10 )
  System.out.println( +sumDealer+ " .");
    else if ( sumDealer > 10 ) {
   sumDealer = sumDealer - 10;
  System.out.println( sumDealer - 10);
   }



//who wins
if(sumPlayer == sumDealer) {
   System.out.println("It's a tie!");
} else if (sumPlayer > sumDealer) {
   System.out.println("Player wins!");
} else {
   System.out.println("Dealer wins!");
}


  }
 }
```

Comment: It's simple -- the house always wins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional conditions in an if statement.

```
if(sumPlayer == sumDealer) {
 System.out.println("It's a tie!");
} else if (sumPlayer > sumDealer) {
 System.out.println("Player wins!");
} else {
 System.out.println("Dealer wins!");
}
```

Sidenote: Java is not the same as JavaScript. In fact they're entirely different.

Comment: wow okay i didnt even know that.. sorry about that! and hey ive tried doing  that but when the newSumPlayer is more or LESS than Dealer, it says player wins...

Comment: Sometimes you're using `sumPlayer` and other times `newSumPlayer`. I don't know what they're supposed to do: are you sure you aren't mixing them up? The code above only uses `sumPlayer` and `sumDealer`.

Comment: or another situation like this:the out put shows like this     Player has 8 , 6 for a hand worth of 
4
Dealer has 4 , 5 for a hand worth of 
9 .
Player wins!, when its meant to be Dealer

Comment: That's because `newSumPlayer` substracts 10 from 8 + 6 (14). Which gives you 4. So the output shows something different. But in the condition, you use `sumPlayer` instead of `newSumPlayer`.

Comment: i use newSumPlayer when the sumPlayer is more than 10 because i need it to be less than 10.. its a baccarat game..same goes to the situation for newSumDealer

Comment: Then use `newSumPlayer` in the checks as well. Or just re-assign the value: `if(sumPlayer > 10) { sumPlayer = sumPlayer - 10;}`. You can shorten this to `if(sumPlayer > 10){ sumPlayer -= 10;}`.

Comment: which means i ll have to remove the newSumPlayer and newSumDealer? and only new sumPlayer and sumDealer for all of it?

Comment: i did that but for one of the outputs i got this.  Player has 3 , 8 for a hand worth of 
1.
Dealer has 3 , 3 for a hand worth of 
6 .
Player wins! ( and its suppose to be Dealer wins!)

Comment: updated already.. i did as what i understood from your feedbacks.. i might have misunderstood some of it and not do it properly.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have not put the conditions for doing all the comparison. Try this:

```
//who wins
if(sumPlayer == sumDealer) {
 System.out.println( " It's a tie! ");
} else if (sumPlayer > sumDealer) {
 System.out.println( " sumPlayer wins ");
} else {
 System.out.println( " sumDealer wins ");
}
```

**EDIT:** As per the comments, it seems you are just printing the values but not assigning them. Try this:

```
if ( sumPlayer <= 10)
   System.out.println(  +sumPlayer+ " .");
 else if (sumPlayer > 10) {
       sumPlayer = sumPlayer - 10;
       System.out.println( sumPlayer - 10);
    }


 System.out.println( "Dealer has " +number3+ " , " +number4+ " for a hand worth of ");
 if ( sumDealer <= 10 )
   System.out.println( +sumDealer+ " .");
 else if ( sumDealer > 10 ) {
    sumDealer = sumDealer - 10;
    System.out.println( sumDealer - 10);
   }
```

Comment: hey i did it already but sometimes for the output i get as following: Player has 3 , 8 for a hand worth of 
1
Dealer has 3 , 3 for a hand worth of 
6 .
Player wins! ( when its meant to be dealer wins!)

Comment: @BithiahBids hey, i don't see mention of worth in your code? You are simply adding the numbers and hence the comparision is happening for sum and not worth.

Comment: hey what do u mean worth? i dont understand. sorry im new to this.. this is just my 3rd of week of class :o

Comment: @BithiahBids This is what you mentioned in the comment "Player has 3 , 8 for a hand worth of 1 ". What is worth here? where is that mentioned in the code?

Comment: if ( sumPlayer <= 10)
     System.out.println(  +sumPlayer+ " .");
     else if (sumPlayer > 10)
     System.out.println( sumPlayer - 10);

Comment: its at the section under //output

Comment: @BithiahBids check my answer edit. You are not assigning the values when sum > 10 , you are just printing it.

Comment: hey i already did that and its showing negative signs now :o i have edited my code above.. please check.. ty

Comment: @BithiahBids i don't see my recommended updates in your code.

Comment: did u check under the //output? cos i think its there